# Cannot create private Kubernetes registry

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a private Kubernetes registry from this tutorial: https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-private-docker-registry-kubernetes/

I implemented this:

```
Generate Self-Signed Certificate
cd /opt 
sudo mkdir certs
cd certs
sudo touch registry.key
cd /opt
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout \
 ./certs/registry.key -x509 -days 365 -out ./certs/registry.crt
ls -l certs/

Create registry folder
cd /opt
mkdir registry
```

Copy-paste `private-registry.yaml` into /opt/registry

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: private-repository-k8s
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: private-repository-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: private-repository-k8s
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: certs-vol
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/certs
          type: Directory
      - name: registry-vol
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/registry
          type: Directory

      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          name: private-repository-k8s
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: "/certs/registry.crt"
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
            value: "/certs/registry.key"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: certs-vol
            mountPath: /certs
          - name: registry-vol
            mountPath: /var/lib/registry


kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl create -f private-registry.yaml
deployment.apps/private-repository-k8s created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$  kubectl get deployments private-repositor                                                               y-k8s
NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
private-repository-k8s   0/1     1            0           12s
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$
```

I have the following questions:

1. I have a control plane and 2 work nodes. Is it possible to have a folder located only on the control plane under `/opt/registry` and deploy images on all work nodes without using shared folders?
2. As alternative more resilient solution I want to have a control plane and 2 work nodes. Is it possible to have a folder located on all work nodes and on the control plane under `/opt/registry` and deploy images on all work nodes without using manually created shared folders? I want Kubernetes to manage repository replication on all nodes. i.e data into `/opt/registry` to be synchronized automatically by Kubernetes.
3. Do you know how I can debug this configuration? As you can see pod is not starting.

EDIT: Log file:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl logs private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq
Error from server (BadRequest): container "private-repository-k8s" in pod "private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$
```

**Attempt 2:**

I tried this configuration deployed from control plane:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi # specify your own size
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /opt/registry # can be any path
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions: # specify the node label which maps to your control-plane node.
        - key: kubernetes1
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane-1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # only 1 node will read/write on the path.
    # - ReadWriteMany # multiple nodes will read/write on the path
```

Note! control plane hostname is `kubernetes1` so I changed the value into above configuration. I get this:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ cd /opt/registry
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl create -f private-registry1.yaml
persistentvolume/pv1 created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS       AGE
default       private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq    0/1     ContainerCreating   0              2d1h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-58dbc876ff-dgs77   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   calico-node-czmzc                          1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   calico-node-q4lxz                          1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-k94z2                   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-nt27m                   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   etcd-kubernetes1                           1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubernetes1        1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-97djs                           1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-d8bzs                           1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h

kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl logs private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq
Error from server (BadRequest): container "private-repository-k8s" in pod "private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
```

Unfortunately again the image is not created.

Comment: do you really need a certificate,TLS and all that stuff ? i mean you are local and it could not make sense.

Comment: btw, are you using containerd ?

Comment: it should be docker. How I can check?

Comment: kubectl get nodes -o wide

Comment: yes: CONTAINER-RUNTIME: containerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st question, you can try creating `PersistentVolume` with node affinity set to specific controlplane node and tie it with the deployment via `PersistentVolumeClaim`.Here's an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi # specify your own size
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /opt/registry # can be any path
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions: # specify the node label which maps to your control-plane node.
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane-1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # only 1 node will read/write on the path.
    # - ReadWriteMany # multiple nodes will read/write on the path
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv1-claim
spec: # should match specs added in the PersistenVolume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Mi
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: private-repository-k8s
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: private-repository-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: private-repository-k8s
    spec:
      volumes:
       - name: task-pv-storage
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: pv1-claim # specify the PVC that you've created. PVC and Deployment must be in same namespace.

      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          name: private-repository-k8s
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: "/certs/registry.crt"
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
            value: "/certs/registry.key"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: task-pv-storage
            mountPath: /opt/registry
```

For question # 2, can you share the logs of your pod?

Comment: how I can list the logs?

Comment: `kubectl log <pod-name>`

Comment: I get https://pastebin.com/2zqqaFhG

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try `kubectl logs <pod-name>`.

Comment: I get this https://pastebin.com/LW9RkNGD

Comment: can you advise, please?

Comment: This link (https://pastebin.com/LW9RkNGD) isn't working. Can you share it again?

Comment: I created a new one: https://pastebin.com/NrvCSQuG  Can you open it?

Comment: Nope. Please share your logs directly here.

Comment: Done, I also updated the post.

Comment: Can you confirm if `registry:2` is correct image name with tag?

Comment: no, I will try that. I think that this is not correctly configured.

Comment: I updated the post with my latest attempt. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247762/discussion-between-tam-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: I have one request: Can you show me how the end yml config should be? Looks like I need to combine mine and yours?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: private-repository-k8s
  labels:
    app: private-repository-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: private-repository-k8s
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: private-repository-k8s
    spec:
      volumes:
       - name: task-pv-storage
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: pv1-claim # specify the PVC that you've created. PVC and Deployment must be in same namespace.

      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          name: private-repository-k8s
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: "/certs/registry.crt"
          - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
            value: "/certs/registry.key"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: task-pv-storage
            mountPath: /opt/registry
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv1-claim
spec: # should match specs added in the PersistenVolume
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi # specify your own size
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /opt/registry # can be any path
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions: # specify the node label which maps to your control-plane node.
        - key: kubernetes1
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane-1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```

Comment: I get: `kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl create -f private-registry1.yaml
deployment.apps/private-repository-k8s created
persistentvolumeclaim/pv1-claim created
The PersistentVolume "pv1" is invalid: spec.nodeAffinity: Required value: Local volume requires node affinity`

Comment: ok, I have added node-affinity as well, can you take the updated file from my reply?