# Cannot delete pod in status ContainerCreating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a failed pod which is not properly created. I used these steps:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ cd /opt/registry
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl create -f private-registry1.yaml
persistentvolume/pv1 created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS       AGE
default       private-repository-k8s-6ddbcd9c45-s6dfq    0/1     ContainerCreating   0              2d1h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-58dbc876ff-dgs77   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   calico-node-czmzc                          1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   calico-node-q4lxz                          1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-k94z2                   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-nt27m                   1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   etcd-kubernetes1                           1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubernetes1        1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-97djs                           1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-proxy-d8bzs                           1/1     Running             4 (125m ago)   2d13h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubernetes1                 1/1     Running             5 (125m ago)   2d13h
```

As you can see the pod is stucked in status ContainerCreating. I tried to delete it:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default       private-repository-k8s    0/1     1            0           2d2h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           2d14h
kube-system   coredns                   2/2     2            2           2d14h
```

Delete command:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl delete -n default deployment private-repository-k8s
deployment.apps "private-repository-k8s" deleted

kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           2d14h
kube-system   coredns                   2/2     2            2           2d14h


kubernetes@kubernetes1:/opt/registry$ kubectl create -f private-registry1.yaml
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "private-registry1.yaml": persistentvolumes "pv1" already exists
```

**private-registry1.yaml configuration:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi # specify your own size
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  local:
    path: /opt/registry # can be any path
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions: # specify the node label which maps to your control-plane node.
        - key: kubernetes1
          operator: In
          values:
          - controlplane-1
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce # only 1 node will read/write on the path.
    # - ReadWriteMany # multiple nodes will read/write on the path
```

Do you know how I can delete `pv1`?

Comment: As per your post, you are able to delete the deployment + pod, but you have not tried deleting the `PersistentVolume` created using the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the PV using the following two commands:

`kubectl delete pv <pv_name> --grace-period=0 --force`

And then deleting the finalizer using:

`kubectl patch pv <pv_name> -p '{"metadata": {"finalizers": null}}'`

As you have created using a file, you can also use the following command to delete the pv:

`kubectl delete -f private-registry1.yaml`

Comment: Thanks, `kubectl delete -f private-registry1.yaml` works but now hen I recreated using ` kubectl create -f private-registry1.yaml`  the pod it's not listed when I run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`. Any idea why?

Comment: It's because your file is not creating a `pod`, it is creating a `PersistentVolume`. Run this command `kubectl get pv --all-namespaces` .

Comment: You must have created the deployment `private-repository-k8s` using some other file/command, the file(private-registry1.yaml) content you have pasted above is only creating a pv.

Comment: ok, got it. See this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569262/cannot-create-private-kubernetes-registry  Looks like I need to combine yml config files. Can you give me example what should be the end yml file, please?